# ClassCastException from SFragment to SFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, classcastexception

I still don't 100% understand the concept/differences of context, activity, fragments, etc, so bear with me.

I'm getting a ClassCastException when calling getActivity() inside a SherlockFragment (note: I also tried getSherlockActivity() to no avail):

```
public abstract class TaskGrabbingFragment extends SherlockFragment {
...
    protected void transferGroupToMe() {
    ...
        Backend.getInstance().modifyTask(new OnModifyTaskResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onModifyTask(Map<String, Object> response) {
                refresh();
            }
        }, (MyActivity) getActivity(),  //ClassCastException
        TaskHelper.TASK_IDS, ids,
        TaskHelper.EMPLOYEE_ID, DomaCareBackend.getInstance().getUserId());
    }
}
```

My logcat output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mycom.task.AllTasksActivity cannot be cast to com.mycom.myapp.MyActivity
at com.mycom.myapp.task.TaskGrabbingFragment.transferGroupToMe(TaskGrabbingFragment.java:69)
at com.mycom.myapp.task.TaskGrabbingFragment.onContextItemSelected(TaskGrabbingFragment.java:47)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1583)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:1992)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:370)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:211)
```

MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity, and the exception occurs in TaskGrabbingFragment, but getActivity() returns AllTasksTabFragment, which is a SherlockFragment. So is there some rule against casting a SherlockFragment to SherlockFragmentActivity? What kind of solution is there to cast a fragment to a fragment activity?

Comment: Then first you must understand the concept of context, activity, fragments, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You're suggesting I master the subject 100% before asking questions?

Answer (score 1):

getActivity() returns AllTasksActivity, not AllTasksTabFragment.
getActivity() returns the Activity that the current fragment is associated with. You should check, if TaskGrabbingFragment is associated with AllTasksActivity or MyActivity.

Comment: You're right, it returns AllTasksActivity, oops. But does it matter? AllTasksActivity and MyActivity both extend SFragmentActivity, doesn't that allow me to cast AllTasksActivity to MyActivity?

Comment: Nope, it only allows you to cast it to AllTasksActivity or SFragmentActivity.
There is a good explanation about this in this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) under the "Casting Objects" part:

Answer (score 1):

Here is some basic theory which is in my mind and I would appreciate if you would correct some of it's drawbacks if it has them:

`Context` is an essence which is used to understand where does some logic is being performed. The most common `Context`s are `Application`, `Activity` and `Service` which imply different types (levels if you want) of `Context`.

`Application` class allows you to provide resources for your application in any program component which refers to it as it represents global (application) context.

`Service` is a program component which allows you to perform some logic in background.

`Activity` is the main UI unit with which user interacts at a moment. It's basically used to provide GUI components, like `View`s.

Nowadays there is a big diversity of devices which run Android. That's why, there is a *fragmentation* problem appears while developing an application which should be executed at most devices as it could.

As one of solutions of this problem Android provides `Fragment` class in it's framework which acts like a reusable container for UI and it's strongly binded to `Activity` class through `Activity`'s lifecycle. One `Activity` may holds a lot of `Fragment`s and has a back stack associated with them.

Recently, Android developers provided an opportunity to create **Nested Fragments** - fragments, so one `Fragment` may serves as a container for other fragments. But in contrast to `Activity`, `Fragment`s haven't back stack for nested fragments.

Your problem seems like you consider `Fragment` as a `Context` when it's not so. `Fragment` is just a plain object - container,- which could be given to user by `Activity` which it is attached to.

And it's strange that `getActivity()` method returns a `Fragment` as it is a final method and it should return an `Activity` object.

The problem may be disguised in the place of your code where you add the `Fragment` to the `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I made a mistake above, though: getActivity() returns AllTasksActivity, which extends SFragmentActivity, so that may have led you astray.

Comment: Then you make wrong casting. These activities extend the same class but they are instances of two different classes. The only thing that you can do is to work with them as with their abstract representation, - `SFragmentActivity` in your case, not using a concrete class casting. BTW, why do you need to cast it to special kind of `SFragmentActivity` - MyActivity` in your case?